# Invalid number of arguments in "auth_request_set" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/projectconf

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, google-oauth, gunicorn

I have been trying to configure my Nginx proxy server with Oauth2Proxy but I am getting the following error while trying to restart my server.

```
2024/03/03 08:07:41 [emerg] 370#370: invalid number of arguments in "auth_request_set" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/someapplication:64
2024/03/03 08:52:44 [warn] 968#968: server name "/var/log/nginx/someapplication_access.log" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/someapplication:5
2024/03/03 08:52:44 [warn] 968#968: server name "/var/log/nginx/someapplication_access.log" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/someapplication:39
2024/03/03 08:52:44 [warn] 969#969: server name "/var/log/nginx/someapplication_access.log" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/someapplication:5
2024/03/03 08:52:44 [warn] 969#969: server name "/var/log/nginx/someapplication_access.log" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/someapplication:39
2024/03/03 09:28:19 [emerg] 2000#2000: unknown "user" variable
```

This is the release I am using for the library

```
https://github.com/pusher/oauth2_proxy/releases/download/v5.0.0/oauth2_proxy-v5.0.0.linux-amd64.go1.13.6.tar.gz
```

Following is the nginx configuration on my server

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name someapplication.com;

location /oauth2/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4180;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Auth-Request-Redirect $request_uri;
}

location / {
    auth_request /oauth2/auth;
    error_page 401 = /oauth2/sign_in;
    # pass information via X-User and X-Email headers to backend
    # requires running with --set-xauthrequest flag auth_request_set         $user $upstream_http_x_auth_request_user;
    auth_request_set $email $upstream_http_x_auth_request_email;
    proxy_set_header X-User $user;
    proxy_set_header X-Email $email;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;            proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_connect_timeout 3s;
    proxy_read_timeout 10s;

    # if you enabled --cookie-refresh, this is needed for it to work with auth_request
    auth_request_set $auth_cookie $upstream_http_set_cookie;                add_header Set-Cookie $auth_cookie;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8002;
}

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/someapplication.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/someapplication.com/privkey.pem;
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
}
```

Comment: First fix the warnings. There is a file called `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/someapplication` and on the line 5 and 39 there is a `server_name` statement with a missing terminating `;`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, I missed assigning the user variable a value hence it was unknown.

```
auth_request_set $user $upstream_http_x_auth_request_user;
```

Worked for me!